# Formato de fecha sin hora minutos segundos

Tags: html, datetime

Hola como puedo hacerle para que en el formato de fecha no me salgan las horas minutos y segundos

Tengo lo siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al momento de querer modificarlos me aparecen asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo es el siguiente, no se que este haciendo mal o me falte algo

```
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fecha de Salida</label>
<div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" name="FechaSalida" class="form-control m-b" value="<?php echo $rowp["FechaSalida"]; ?>"></div>

<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fecha de Llegada</label>
<div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" name="FechaLlegada" class="form-control m-b" value="<?php echo $rowp["FechaLlegada"]; ?>"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Modifica la fecha antes de mostrarla en el campo.

Puedes hacer un format a la fecha si estas utilizando angular 2 4 en adelante:

```
new DatePipe('en-CO').transform( fecha, 'yyyy/MM/dd');
```

puedes darle el formato que quieras.

Si estas utilizando Javascript para cargar la fecha puedes realizar esto:

```
var hoy = new Date();
dia = hoy.getDate();
mes = hoy.getMonth();
anio= hoy.getFullYear();
fechaContact = String(dia+"/"+mes+"/"+anio);
fechaMostrar = new Date(fecha_actual);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pasa Primero el valor a $fechaSalida = strtotime($rowp["FechaSalida"]), para que puedas darle formato con date() https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php

```
$fechaSalida = strtotime($rowp["FechaSalida"]);
$fechaSalida = date('d/m/Y',$fechaSalida);
echo $fechaSalida;
```

Comment: Que tal Ramiro, agregue las variables y puse el echo pero me sale el puro formato la fecha dd/mm/aaaa no me jala la fecha que se le agrego anteriormente

Comment: que tipo de variable es FechaSalida en tu DB, creo saber porque, el formato que lleva el input es yyyy-mm-dd, lo que puedes hacer es cambiar el formato date('Y-m-d',$fechaSalida)

Comment: Los 3 son datetime

Comment: Intenta dando este formato date('Y-m-d',$fechaSalida) u otra checa como lo estas enviando desde el php a la DB

Comment: Cambie la variable {datetime} por {date} y basto con solo eso para que me dejara de aparecer.

Comment: ohh ya, ahora entiendo, como tenias un **datetime** al enviarlo sólo enviabas la fecha debido a esto en la BD se guardaba la hora nula, buena opcion el hecho de cambiar el tipo de valor